# Python : encode string

Tags: python, email, utf-8, python-2.4

I'd like sending a message (an e-mail) which contains strings from a database with some special characters

Example (in french): `"Bonjour ça va ?"`

Is it possible to encode the mail to utf-8 mode ?
When I write this message on a file, I just have to set his property to "utf-8" and then he displays it successfully, how can do the same thing into my mail?

Comment: How are you sending the email? Do you have any code yet?

Comment: I'm just using "smtplib" library and "sendmail()" function, that seems to works fine, except the special characters problem. Should i use another method ?

Comment: Take a look at the [`email` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) to generate your email message; it handles proper encoding and MIME.

Comment: @antho Your working code itself would go a long way to helping people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

did you try?:

```
u"Bonjour ça va ?"
```